# Bash string comparison keeps returning wrong result

Tags: bash

I am trying to find out why my comparison logic keeps failing. I keep getting **no match** with each attempt.

```
#!/bin/bash

AddComponentToComponent "home-navbar" "app"

...

AddComponentToComponent() {
  if [[ "$1" == "home-navbar" ]] && [[ "$2" == "app" ]]; then
    echo "match"
  else
    echo "no match"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the code you posted into a new file and run/modify it until it shows the problem you say it does. Then update your post

Comment: Cannot reproduce problem. It matches.

Comment: works when i tried it

Comment: You need to have function declaration before function usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match is working according to the comparison but your example will not work because you have declared the function after the call.

If you desire this order in your code then you could declare a `main` function

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
AddComponentToComponent "home-navbar" "app"
 }

AddComponentToComponent() {
if [[ "$1" == "home-navbar" ]] && [[ "$2" == "app" ]]; then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "no match"
fi
}


main "$@"
```

Comment: Yes I did run it.